# adding look to python script causes script to fail

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

i am trying to create a script to continuously print text from a certain element using selenium and chrome driver

when i run this script all works fine

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSD/?exchange=BITSTAMP")
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/header/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div""").text
print(price)
```

but when i add a loop like this

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSD/?exchange=BITSTAMP")
price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/header/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div""").text
while True:
print(price)
time.sleep(1)
```

the script closes immediately after running it

did i make a noob mistake? can anyone help me out?

Comment: Is there any error/exception? Adding just a infinity loop with a `print()` and `sleep()` will never cause error. If python returns any errors please add them to your post

Comment: you have to use `find_element_by_xpath` inside loop to get new value

Comment: you have wrong indentations in loop - maybe this is your problem. You should run code in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see if it displaya any error message.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work;

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r"C:\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/BTCUSD/?exchange=BITSTAMP")
while True:
    price = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[2]/div[4]/div/header/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div""").text

    print(price)
    time.sleep(1)
```